# php login script not working after 3 database entries

Tags: php

it seems my login script only works for a short period of time. After 2 users have successfully registered and logged on, the 3rd user isn't successful in logging in despite data entries matching perfectly with database values (usernames and passwords).Here is my simplified login script.`

```
<?php
session_start();
$hostname = 'ommitted';
$dbname   = 'ommitted';
$username = 'ommitted'; 
$password = 'ommitted';

mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host has failed, perhaps the service is down!');
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');

$userName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$passWord=md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])); 


$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and  password='$password' AND type='Student'";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
if ($rows==1) 
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    header("Location: /index.html");
}

else 
{
    echo "user name and password not found<br><a href='login.php'>Log in</a>";
}
?>
```

Everything works perfectly fine initially except when i try to login with the correct login data on multiple web browsers, the first two logins are successful but then for the 3rd login attempt i get an error, i'm faced with the error message "user name and password not found", which of course points to the else statement. I have no idea whats happening, could this be a bug, the login scripts works at one point in time and doesn't work at another. There are no syntactical errors but the problem persists. When i drop all entries in my database and try to register again with 3 new entries, the exact same thing happens, some of the logins are successful but the 3rd or 4th i'm faced with the error message 'user name and password not found'. I even tried copying the usernames and password directly from my database but to no avail. Could there be a problem with the login script? can it be refactored? does anyone know what is happening?

Note, I'm testing this login script through a file management system on my webhost

Comment: you've got major security vulnerabilities. Fix that before going live with this

Comment: 1- Don't use MD5 for hashing passwords, use native `password_*` functions in PHP. 2- Don't concatenate data to a query, use Prepared statements instead.

Comment: check what result you are getting from database that will help you to debug.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy, all the queries are successful, the registration also works fine, the problem seems to come from this login script

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale, i'm aware of this, its a small test nothing is really at risk of being compromised

Comment: if you provide correct credentials then you must get one row. your logic is in manner if you dont get exactly one row then else part will be executed. so check their

Comment: Echo your query and run it in MySql directly to make sure that it is really correct. There shouldn't be a reason for it to stop working at the 3rd attempt. Having said that, using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` would be a better idea than using MD5.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy Problem Solved, thank you very much, i have found the problem, i have overlooked the number of rows